# Вызов метода из UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms

День добрый! Мучаюсь который день, может подскажите?

В основной Форме есть функция

```
public void MessageReader(string Name)
{ .... }
```

И в UserControl:

```
private void UsersBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   //MessageReader("Name"); - так вызвать метод не получается.
}
```

Искал в Google, но пока ответа не нашел... Как правильно?
Спасибо!

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55668/discussion-on-question-by-brave-lime----usercontrol).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `UserControl`-e:

```
public Form1 ParentForm { get; set; }
private void UsersBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
  if (ParentForm != null)
    ParentForm.MessageReader("Name"); 
}
```

В форме:

```
userControl.ParentForm = this;
```

Answer (score 0):

Правильно будет так:

```
private void UsersBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   if(this.Parent is NeededForm)//подставьте тип своей формы с методом
   {
       ((NeededForm)this.Parent).MessageReader("Name");
   }
}
```

или даже короче, если используете C#6

```
private void UsersBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   (this.Parent as NeededForm)?.MessageReader("Name");
}
```

В WinForms каждый контрол по умолчанию имеет ссылку на родительский контейнер. Исключением являются только формы, и то не всегда. Родитель вписывается автоматически, при добавлении одного контрола в коллекцию дочерних другого контрола. Работает и наоборот, вы можете указать родителя, и контрол автоматически будет помещен в коллекцию дочерних контролов родителя.

В коде выше все просто, проверяем что родитель нужного нам типа и вызываем метод, в противном случае ничего не делаем, ведь не у каждой формы есть описанный вами метод. Разумеется ваш контрол должен размещаться прямо на форме, без промежуточных панелей, таблиц и прочих контейнеров.

Если нужны промежуточные контейнеры, то либо вариант из соседнего ответа, либо меняем архитектуру на более гибкую и менее капризную.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!